# Retry with useMutation (React Query)

Tags: reactjs, react-query

How can I do a retry when the mutation fails in react-query?
If there is an error, I would like to retry the mutation 3 times.

I read this [thread](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/374) where Tanner mentioned that `you’ll have to build your own promise retry wrapper.` but, how can I do that?

My function is:

```
const [accessSelectPage, accessSelectPageInfo] = useMutation(
    () =>
      axios.post(
        POST_ACCESS_SELECT_PAGE_EP(token ?? ''),
        {},
        {
          headers: { 'X-Campaign-ID': campaignID }
        }
      ),
    {
      onSuccess: (responseOnSuccess) => {
        console.log('accessSelectPage', responseOnSuccess)
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log('accessSelectPage error', error)
      }
    }
  )
```

Note: Yes, I know that v3 has an option "retry", but I'm using v2, and updating react-query is not viable for several reasons.

Answer (score 7):

ReactQuery.v3 supports [retries](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#retry)

```
  const [accessSelectPage, accessSelectPageInfo] = useMutation(
    () =>
      axios.post(
        POST_ACCESS_SELECT_PAGE_EP(token ?? ''),
        {},
        {
          headers: { 'X-Campaign-ID': campaignID }
        }
      ),
    {
      onSuccess: (responseOnSuccess) => {
        console.log('accessSelectPage', responseOnSuccess)
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.log('accessSelectPage error', error)
      }
    },
    {
      retry: 3
    }
  )
```

For ReactQuery.v2 suggest using [`axios-retry`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-retry) as it seems like v2 doesn't support retry according to [source code](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/blob/6e2e37ea5fe180a6d5ee3dedf76bd72160406b2a/src/react/useMutation.ts)

Comment: Yes, I know that v3 has an option "retry", but I'm using v2, and updating react-query is not viable for several reasons. Any idea how can I do with v2?

Comment: @Alfrex92 try using axios-retry

Comment: If you also want manual retries (e.g. a `retry` button for the user), you have to reset the React-Query mutation (`reset()` method in the returned object from `useMutation`) and then you also have to invoke that mutation again (`mutate()`)! - Otherwise the mutation is only reset but nothing is send again.